# How to distinguish constant string from char* in C macro

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I want to write a macro to write a string, using the compile-time optimisation of knowing the length of a string literal. But I need to detect misuse, using pointers.

Here's what I mean:

```
void transmit(const char *data, int length);
#define tx_string(x) transmit((x), sizeof(x) -1)
void func(char *badmsg) {
  tx_string("GO");    // ok
  tx_string(badmsg);  // not OK
}
```

With the second call, the size will be nonsense (sizeof a pointer).

I want to produce a compile-time error if I attempt to use tx_string on anything other than a string literal. This is using gcc; is there some gcc thing I can use to do this?

Edit: I work with data buffers that may contain nulls or not be terminated by nulls. I REALLY want to prevent pointers being used for this, and prevent run-time `strlen()` use.

Edit 2:

Here's an example which would cause a problem.
I'll invent an imaginary protocol where I have to tell a 16-bit microcontroller an address using the command GO followed by an address as 16-bit raw (two 8-bit characters), and I want to go from address 0.

```
#define GOSEQ "GO\000\000"

void func(void) {
  char *bad = GOSEQ;
  tx_string(GOSEQ); // ok, sends 4 bytes: GO and two zero bytes
  tx_string(bad);   // bad, using runtime strlen sends two characters "GO"
}
```

I feel sure there must be some kind of gcc builtin check for this. I see the Linux kernel sources using compile-time distinction tricks like this a lot.. but can't lay my hands on a specific one quickly.

So far "Windows programmer"'s idea looks good, but a more meaningful compile-time error would be a bonus.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, since you cannot use string concatenation with pointers etc, maybe you can use:

```
#define STRLIT(x)  x ""
```

If the argument to `STRLIT` is not a string literal, you will get a compilation error.

Adapting the general to your specific macro:

```
#define tx_string(x) transmit((x ""), sizeof(x) - 1)
```

Comment: This looks like a winner! I'll just wait a bit in case someone comes up with the perfect builtin test or something.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
#define tx_string(x) transmit(x, strlen(x)) // No need for extra parentheses
```

GCC will optimize out the `strlen` call, and I'm sure other compilers will too.  Don't waste your time on this stuff.

**Test file:**

```
#include <string.h>
void transmit(const char *, size_t);
#define tx_string(x) transmit(x, strlen(x))
void func(void)
{
    tx_string("abcdef");
}
```

**Resulting assembly:**

I trimmed noise out of the assembly, this is the important stuff.  Notice that it never calls `strlen`, instead it just uses the number 6:

```
.LC0:
    .string "abcdef"

func:
    movl    $6, %esi
    movl    $.LC0, %edi
    jmp     transmit
```

Comment: OK, but I work with data buffers that may contain nulls or not be terminated by nulls. I REALLY want to prevent pointers being used for this, and prevent run-time strlen() use.

Comment: @blueshift: In C, pointers and arrays are interchangeable as arguments to functions.  Why do you need to prevent pointers from being passed?  It does not make sense to me.  I am also unsure why you need to prevent runtime `strlen` use.  Could you explain that?

Comment: @Deitrich Epp: My previous comment should explain it. I'll edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @blueshift: I'll leave this answer up because it is still useful.  You are free to accept one of the other answers below.

Comment: @Deitrich Epp: Agreed, in many cases your assumption would be valid, just not what I need here. I often tell people not to worry about premature optimisation myself :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#define tx_string(x) ("i came, i concatenated, i discarded " x, transmit((x), sizeof(x) - 1))
```

Not quite perfect because some joker could call tx_string(+1)

Comment: I see what you did there. Sneaky. I'm surprised that sizeof(+1) compiles.
Actually if the discard string is moved to the right of x, it looks pretty good.. can't immediately think of anything invalid that compiles.

Comment: You're right, Jonathan Leffler's answer solves my minor defect.  Meanwhile, it should not really be surprising that sizeof some int compiles and its value is the size of an int.